# Apache: How can I make my localhost on 192.168.1.101 visible from 192.168.1.102?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I've setup a Apache web server on Ubuntu Linux. I can see it as http://localhost and http://192.168.1.101 and http://default.local/. All work well.
But I can't see localhost from other machines in my network using IP address: http://192.168.1.101 or http://default.local/

I also have added `192.168.1.101` to both computers' `/etc/hosts/`

I added the lines below to my apache conf:

```
`Allow from 192.168.1`
```

but it did not work. It says "the connection has timed out".

what should i do?

**PS:**

```
adp@adp-desktop:~$ sudo netstat -ap | grep apache
tcp        0      0 *:www                   *:*                     LISTEN      10581/apache2   
tcp        0      0 localhost:www           localhost:46017         ESTABLISHED 10586/apache2
```

Apache conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName default.local    
    DocumentRoot /home/www/public_html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/www/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        #AllowOverride None
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all

    </Directory>
```

Comment: What does the `Listen` directive say ?

Comment: it listens 80... as i said everything is OK. it just can't be seen from other computers.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is clear for you but the hostname `localhost` is a local alias on every machine pointing to 127.0.0.1 which is the local loopback interface. It is therefore only accessible from the local machine.

When you have such problem, what you want to do is check what IP the Apache socket is bound to. In order to do this, you can use `netstat -ap | grep apache`. This will give you a line containing either `locahost:80` or `*:80`. Note that the port number may be replaced by a more intelligible name such as `http`.

The first one will mean that Apache is only bound to the local interface therefore can't be reached from other computers on the network. The first one will mean that Apache can be reached from the network providing that traffic flows are allowed and fucntionnal (no firewall per example).

**EDIT :** Considering the configuration you posted, you should check network connectivity. Make sure both PCs can ping each other and make sure you are trying to access the correct IP.

Comment: thanks. i run your command, and added to question. will you check it and tell what does it mean?

Comment: can you also post you Apache configuration ?

Comment: yes, i did. please check the question.

Comment: If you've posted your entire apache.conf you've got a real problem. That looks more like a vhost.conf file.

Comment: you ar right. i set ServerName to my conf. now it is accessible view http://default.local too. and i set it in my laptop's hosts file. but the problem persists.

Comment: i also moved localhost definition out of vhost declaration. but everything is still like before. still timeout. i think this has nothing to do with apache, but by network.